# How many miles is the runner from her home if she runs $6$ miles north, then $5$ miles at an angle of $15^\circ$ east of north?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A person leaves her home and runs $6$ miles due north. Then, she turns through the angle $\alpha = 15^\circ$ east of north and runs $5$ miles in the new direction. How many miles is she now from her home?

Round your answer to two decimal places.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share your thoughts/attempts, confusion and where you are stuck?

Comment: Perhaps include a picture of the situation?

Comment: It would also be nice if the question title were a short version of the question.

Comment: You are expected to do this in the plane.  Use the law of cosines.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$\color{blue}{Blue}$ vector: run north for $A = 5$ miles.

$\color{purple}{Purple}$ vector: run north for $B = 6$ miles.

How far from the origin is the runner? That is, what is the length of the black, dashed line?

---

@Ross Millikan illuminates the path to success: use **the law of cosines.**

$$
C^{2} = \color{blue}{A^{2}}  + \color{purple}{B^{2}} - 2 \color{blue}{A}\color{purple}{B} \cos c
$$

The angle is
$$
 c = 180 - 15 = 165 \qquad \left( = \pi - \frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{11}{12}\pi\right)
$$
The cosine of the angle is
$$
  \cos c = -\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2 \sqrt{2}}
$$

How long is the dashed vector?
$$
 \sqrt{C^{2}} 
= \sqrt{\color{blue}{A^{2}}  + \color{purple}{B^{2}} - 2 \color{blue}{A}\color{purple}{B} \cos c} 
= \sqrt{15 \sqrt{2}+15 \sqrt{6}+61} \approx 10.9067
$$

In agreement with and thanks to @Deepak.

Comment: If she turns $15^\circ$ *east* of *north*, I think that angle should be $165^\circ$ and the answer should be $\approx 10.91$.

Comment: @Deepak: Aha. I misread the problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Cosine Rule, you can put the path on a grid with the origin at the initial point. Find the vertical (North positive, South negative) and horizontal (East positive, West negative) coordinates of the destination.

Vertical: $y= 6 + 5\cos 15^\circ$

Horizontal: $x = 5\sin 15^\circ$

To find the distance, you need to square those, add and then take the square root.

$d = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = (6 + 5\cos 15^\circ)^2 + (5\sin 15^\circ)^2 = \sqrt{61 + 60\cos 15^\circ} \approx 10.91 \mathrm{miles}$, where I used the identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ at one point in the simplification.